# AngularJS - Display the sum of a collection in array (without use a javascript in my controller)

Tags: angularjs

I looking for how to display sum of result from array **without use a javascript in my controller**.

**My object:**

```
usages:[
       { frontends: [{errors: 1}, {errors: 2}, {errors: 3}] },
       { frontends: [{errors: 2}, {errors: 1}, {errors: 1}] }
]
```

**My HTML template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="usage in foo.usages">
  <span>{{usage.frontends ???? }}&thinsp;%</span> 
</tr>
```

**I want this result:**

```
+-------+
+   6   +
+-------+
+   4   +
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ng-init`:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="usage in usages" ng-init="total = {}" >
      <td ng-repeat="front in usage.frontends" ng-init="total.errors = front.errors + total.errors">
          <div ng-if="$last">{{ total.errors }}</div>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Check the working demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duwkb871/41/)